# Add leading zeros to numbers within string

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a string with several numbers and need to add leading zeros to some (not all) of the numbers. Only numbers that are single digits and have a letter in front need a leading zero.

input: `"Z9_M50_P3_2X_MY_STRING"`

output: `"Z09_M50_P03_2X_MY_STRING"`

Comment: What did you try? Please show your effort.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
(?<=[a-zA-Z])(\d)(?!\d)
```

replace by this:

```
0\1
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sQVBs6/3)

Sample Source: ( [run here](https://ideone.com/8dXeE3) )

```
import re

regex = r"(?<=[a-zA-Z])(\d)(?!\d)"
test_str = ("Z9_M50_P3_2X_MY_STRING")
subst = "0\\1"
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)
```

Comment: what 0\1 mean? i know it adds 0 but why its has 1?